# Make vim use the font colour I specified for comments for JavaDoc comments in .java files

Tags: java, vim, themes, javadoc

I already found that I can specify the font colour for comments using `hi Comment` in my color scheme file. This also works perfectly fine for normal `// line comments` and `/* block comments */`.

However, my JavaDoc comments look like this:

[image: JavaDoc comment]

How can I change the font colour of `Method that does stuff`, `@param` and `parameter`, respectively?

Comment: There are a great many vim questions on this site, so I’m a little surprised this has been closed. That said, pedantically it is off-topic here—and thankfully *very* on-topic at [vi.se]! I spend a lot of time there; come check us out!

Answer (score 2):

I’ve got this line in my vimrc to disable javadoc highlighting entirely:

```
" Do NOT highlight javadoc specially: it is distracting
let java_ignore_javadoc = 1
```

If you want to customize them, you should find out the syntax groups they are using and highlight those. (My [synstax](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-synstax) plugin, alongside many others, can assist you in this.)